# Columns from backend(API ) not working for useState

Tags: reactjs, function

I am fetching data from backend for Drag and Drop

```
const [productsList, setProductsList] = useState([]);
const loadData=async() =>
  {
  
   const response=await fetch("http://localhost:8000/api/getcandidates/");
   
   const data=await response.json();
  // console.log(data);
   const savedate=data.candidate;
   var myObject = JSON.parse(savedate);
   setProductsList(myObject);
   
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    loadData();
   },[]);
```

So I got respond as

```
const items2FromBackend = [
    { id: 1, content: "First task",  title: "JAVA DEVELOPER2", name:"shanu", status: "Inprogress", Skill: "HTML, CSS, JavaScript" , view: "", exp: "4.6Yrs", ctc: " 5LK/A", exctc: " 5LK/A", location: "kakkand", np: "2 Mth" },
    { id: 2,  content: "First task",  title: "JAVA DEVELOPER", name:"shanu", status: "Inprogress", Skill: "HTML, CSS, JavaScript" , view: "", exp: "4.6Yrs", ctc: " 5LK/A", exctc: " 5LK/A", location: "kakkand", np: "2 Mth"},
    { id: 3,  content: "First task",  title: "JAVA DEVELOPER2", name:"shanu", status: "Inprogress", Skill: "HTML, CSS, JavaScript" , view: "", exp: "4.6Yrs", ctc: " 5LK/A", exctc: " 5LK/A", location: "kakkand", np: "2 Mth"},
    { id: 4,  content: "First task",  title: "JAVA DEVELOPER", name:"shanu", status: "Inprogress", Skill: "HTML, CSS, JavaScript" , view: "", exp: "4.6Yrs", ctc: " 5LK/A", exctc: " 5LK/A", location: "kakkand", np: "2 Mth" },
    { id: 5,  content: "First task",  title: "JAVA DEVELOPER", name:"shanu", status: "Inprogress", Skill: "HTML, CSS, JavaScript" , view: "", exp: "4.6Yrs", ctc: " 5LK/A", exctc: " 5LK/A", location: "kakkand", np: "2 Mth" }
  ];
```

and this for drag and drop uuid

```
const columnsFromBackend = {
    [uuid()]: {
      name: "Inprogress", 
      items: productsList
    },
    [uuid()]: {
      name: "Schedule",
      items: []
    },
    [uuid()]: {
      name: "Rejection",
      items: []
    },
    [uuid()]: {
      name: "Waiting",
      items: []
    }
  };

const [columns, setColumns] = useState(columnsFromBackend);
```

useState(columnsFromBackend) is not working for back end fetch data `productsList`.But its working for hardcore data. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Since you still need to await for the `columnsFromBackend` you need to use the setter instead of making it as a "default value". If you call `useState(defaultValue)`. the parameter inside is the defaultValue and it will only be set once.

so in your case what you can do isv put it inside a useState:

```
const [columns, setColumns] = useState([]);

useState(() => {
  setColumns(columnsFromBackend);
}, [columnsFromBackend])
```

So every time there is a change from `columnsFromBackend` it will update your state.

Comment: @I am L thanks for the reply. Still not working

Comment: @Shanukk I'm missing something from your code then, can you post the whole code without cutting it?